# How to remove characters in filename up to and including second underscore

Tags: macos, unix, sed, rename, file-rename

I've been looking around for a while on this and can't seem to find a solution on how to use sed to do this. I have a file that is named:

FILE_772829345_D594_242_25kd_kljd.mov

that I want to be renamed

D594_242_25kd_kljd.mov

I currently have been trying to get sed to work for this but have only been able to remove the first second of the file:

```
echo 'FILE_772829345_D594_242_25kd_kljd.mov' | sed 's/[^_]*//'
_772829345_D594_242_25kd_kljd.mov
```

How would I get sed to do the same instruction again, up to the second underscore?

Comment: `sed 's/[^_]*_[^_]*_//'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the filename is in a shell variable, you don't even need to use `sed`, just use a [shell expansion with `#`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) to trim through the second underscore:

```
filename="FILE_772829345_D594_242_25kd_kljd.mov"
echo "${filename#*_*_}"    # prints "D594_242_25kd_kljd.mov"
```

BTW, if you're going to use `mv` to rename the file, use its `-i` option to avoid file getting overwritten if there are any name conflicts:

```
mv -i "$filename" "${filename#*_*_}"
```

Comment: I used this method!  Worked out well...just have to figure out how to allow my script to accept multiple files now.
   
   `echo "Please drag your file here:"
    read filename
    path=$(dirname "${filename}")
    file=$(basename "${filename}")
    mv -i "$path/$file" "$path/${file#*_*_}"`

Comment: @DerekEdwards Try `read -a filenames; for filename in "${filenames[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: Thank you! That worked.  Can you explain what that is doing?!  I'll look into it regardless.

Comment: @DerekEdwards `read -a` reads input as an array rather than a plain variable (and its quote/escape/etc parsing seems to match the way Finder encodes filepaths). `for filename in [list of words]; do` iterates over the "words", and `"${filenames[@]}" expands to the contents of the `filenames` array, with each element treated as a "word".

Comment: @DerekEdwards BTW, if this answer worked for you, please [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Or just `for filename in *_*_*; do mv ...; done` to loop over all files with two underscores.

Answer (score 1):

If all your files are named similarly, you can use `cut` which would be a lot simpler than `sed` with a regex:

```
cut -f3- -d_ <<< "FILE_772829345_D594_242_25kd_kljd.mov"
```

Output:

```
D594_242_25kd_kljd.mov
```